# What should I put in the Request Body to send an email with a hyperlink?

Tags: json, api, email, hyperlink

I would like to send an email with a hyperlink.
Currently, I am sending mails via V3 Mail Send API.
However, I am having trouble sending emails with hyperlinks.
What should I put in the Request Body to send an email with a hyperlink?

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please [edit] your question and describe what the problem is. What happens when you try to send a link? What did you expect to happen? Show the code you use, as  a [mcve]. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hyperlink can cause the content to be escaped and break up the api call. I'm not sure if this is the issue you are having or if the link just doesn't appear as a hyperlink when the email is received?
For the first issue, escape the forward slashes. The second issue, I would send the email in html format if that's possible and that should keep the hyperlink in it's original format.